I'm trying to add a button into my circuit that controls the pattern for my arduino
ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect) {
    slow_counter++;
    
    if (slow_counter >= 125) {  // Adjust this value to control the speed of chasing
        slow_counter = 0;
        if (current_pattern == 0) {
            chase_leds(); // Call chase_leds if current pattern is chase_leds
        } else {
            stay_lit_chase_leds(); // Call stay_lit_chase_leds otherwise
        }
    }
}

ISR(INT1_vect) {
  // Toggle between regular chase and stay-lit chase patterns
  if (current_pattern == 0) {
    current_pattern = 1; // Change to stay-lit chase pattern
  } else {
    current_pattern = 0; // Change to regular chase pattern
  }
}

void setup() {
    DDRD = 0x3F; // Set PD0-2, PD4-5 as output (0b00111111)
    DDRB = 0x07; // Set PB0-PB2 as output
    PORTD = 0x08; // Enable pull-up resistor on PD3
    InitTimer();
    adc_init();
    // Enable global interrupts
    sei(); 
    // Configure external interrupt INT0 for the button at PD4
    EICRA |= (1 << ISC00); // Trigger on any logic change
    EIMSK |= (1 << INT1); // Enable INT1 interrupt
    // Initialize serial communication
    Serial.begin(57600);
}

int main(void) {
    setup();
    while (1) {
        // Main loop
    }
    return 0;
}

I'm really clueless in this Timer and Interrupt topic. So i really don't know how to do it.
So I'm trying to add a button to change the pattern. I'm only permitted to use PD2 and 3 for my button. I don't know why is not registering any button press right now and it wont change my pattern.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to add a schematic of your circuit and a [mre]. Are you aware that your comment Set PD0-2, PD4-5 as output does not tell the truth?

It is a common error to use edge-sensitive interrupts for buttons, because they bounce.

This may be Arduino hardware, but it is not Arduino Sketch framework code, but does use Arduino library code (Serial). Is that confused mix intentional?  Why are you even starting Serial? You don't appear to be using it.  How do we know the issue is not in the unseen chase_leds(), stay_lit_chase_leds(), InitTimer() or adc_init()?  You need to apply normal debug techniques to narrow it down a bit perhaps.  The most obvious issue however is lack of debounce. You could simply block any further toggle until the timer handler runs.

Given the amount of unseen code here there may be multiple issues, but lack of switch debounce is certainly one of them.
In this case, ignoring interrupts until the timer interrupt occurs is a simple method of debounce.  You could achieve that by using a flag sti in one handler and cleared in the other or more simply by disabling the button interrupt until the timer interrupt thus:
ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect) 
{
    // Enable button interrupt
    EIMSK |= (1 << INT1);

    ...
}


ISR(INT1_vect)
{
    // Disable button interrupt
    EIMSK &= ~(1 << INT1);

    ...
}

In that way, the pattern flag cannot be toggled repeatedly between pattern updates, through either switch-bounce or multiple activations.
Additionally:
EICRA |= (1 << ISC00); // Trigger on any logic change

Is probably wrong. You do not want to toggle on press, then again on release, you end up with no change. Suggest:
EICRA |= (1 << ISC00) | (1 << ISC01) ; // Trigger on rising edge.

... or falling-edge, depending on how the button is wired and whether you want the change in button press or button release.
